# Update query with multiple tables and limit option

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
Update table2 t2
set t2.c1=t1.c1
inner join table1 t1 on ( t1.c2 = t2.c2)
where t2.c1 = "-1";
```

I want to execute the above query which will update the `table2` column from `table1` column ON INNER JOIN matching conditions. It is working fine. I am running a migration where the rows count are in million in both tables. I thought of limiting the update query in batches for query optimization but limit is not allowed in update query.

I can try with select query with limit option, but updating multiple columns would not work with this below query.

```
update table2 t2
set t2.c1=<?>
where t1.c2 = ( select c2 from table);
```

Can anyone help to use update query with optimization? Will updating millions row have any impact?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using? That initial statement is not valid T-SQL, so I assume the former.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry for the confusion. I am using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the `limit`ing clause to the joined table, like so:

```
update table2 t2
inner join (
    select c1, c2
    from table1
    order by c2
    limit ?, ?
) t1 on t1.c2 = t2.c2
set t2.c1 = t1.c1
where t2.c1 = -1
```

Comment: thank you your answer. It return me an error with *MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join (* with the exact query. Also, Could you explain how this select c1,c2 works with inner join for my understanding?

Comment: @MarkWaugh: sorry there was a syntax problem (the `set` clause comes after the `join`) - that was wrong in your original query already.

Comment: The subquery selects a limited subset of `table1`, then the result is joined with the outer table for update. You can use adjust the question marks to perform the update in batches.

Comment: It is working :-) the sub-query results is treated as t1 resutls which will do a inner join with t2. Am I right? btw, it is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you *really* want to do, but you can update multiple columns with `update` and `limit`.

The following is fine:

```
update table2 t2
    set t2.c1 = <?>,
        t2.c3 = ?
    where t1.c2 = ( select c2 from table)
    limit 100;
```

Comment: 1. LIMIT 100 which you mentioned will apply for UPDATE query which mysql does not allow it ( correct me if I am wrong). 2. t2.c1=<?> this value is fetched from t1.c1 and your query doesn't have such thing. 3. The mentioned WHERE condition is to update to single row which would not work as I said and was looking for bulk update rows with matching condition of 2 tables.

Comment: @MarkWaugh . . . MySQL DOES support `LIMIT` in `UPDATE` -- but not when there is a `JOIN`.  If the values are coming from the other table, then this approach does not work.

Comment: Fine. I want to update table2 column with table1 column with conditions matching with limit option (limit for optimization). Could you guide me please.